# ストアドプロシージャでSelectした結果をArrayで持ってくることができますか？

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Visual Studio2013のC#でAPIを開発しています。

現在、全てのデータをSelectしてそれをOUTPUT Parameterで持ってこようと思います。
で、OUTPUT ParameterをどんなタイプにしたらArray型で持ってくるのができますでしょうか？

ちなみにMySQLを使っています。

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectHistory
      @Value [Data type??] OUTPUT
      AS
      SELECT @Value = Address FROM History
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答としては、OUTPUTパラメータでArray形式の戻り値を得ることはできません。

替わりに、Procedure内でSELECT文を書いて、そのまま結果セットを受け取ってください。